# How to insert a time into sql table?

Tags: sql, oracle

On Oracle 11g, I ran the following code first:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
create table table1(mytime timestamp);
```

Then I wanted to add a row to my table:

```
insert into table1(mytime)
    values(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-24 07:16:11'));
```

I also tried without TO_TIMESTAMP:

```
insert into table1(mytime)
    values('2014-12-24 07:16:11');
```

both gave me the same error:

```
--A * here: ...values('2014...
--                    *
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should've been easily google-able.

But here you go:

```
insert into table1(mytime)
values(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-24 07:16:11', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: Does this mean I cannot define a format once for all?

Comment: Yes, it can't be done once for all. Although the other option is to use [Timestamp literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) by specifying the time to `fractional_seconds_precision`. Like this: `'2014-12-24 07:16:11.xxx'`

Answer (score 1):

> [TO_TIMESTAMP( string1 [, fmt ] ['nlsparam'] )](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)
>  The optional fmt
>   specifies the format of char. If you omit fmt, then char must be in
>   the default format of the TIMESTAMP datatype, which is determined by
>   the **NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT** initialization parameter.

Here you can see that it is not `nls_date_format` but `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` that you have to change.

Use;

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Then try to insert the data.

**NOTE**
Its always better to use `TO_DATE` and  `TO_TIMESTAMP` with proper format like

```
TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02 14:10:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Or you can use the [Date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)
like

```
TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:50.124'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in my case,    nls_date_format    works just fine. I am sure at some point of time your suggestion will be needed.